# When SortedDictionary is enumerated does it return KeyValuePairs in expected order?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, idictionary, sorteddictionary

When I have `SortedDictionary<TK, TV>` in .NET and I want to enumerate it as `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TK, TV>>` does it enumerate in expected order?

That is `KeyValuePair<TK, TV>` with lowest key is returned as first, folloved by `KeyValuePair<TK, TV>` with second lowest key etc.?

*Note: Only answer backed up by reference will be accepted.*

Comment: This is absurd.  Use google to find links.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Before suggesting to do something (that I have indeed tried) you should try it. It is not easy to to google clear answer to this, I have tried 20 different searches. And much more absurd thinks are asked on SO. There is no note about particular ordering granted when enumerating `KeyValuePairs` of `SortedDictionary` in documentation. That probably means that documentation is poor but that is not the point. The fact that any other behavior would be really unexpected does not mean that I can depend on assumptions in critical applications. I need reference.

Comment: @HansPassant: While I understand the sentiment that SO is not a link searching service (which IMHO only applies to this question if the answer is easily found on the docs), this is the first time - inside and outside of the StackExchange network - I have ever seen the requirement to back up any kind of statement with supporting evidence being considered as "absurd".

Comment: Ought to be a little evident that it was an absurd requirement.  The answer the OP selected has no links or supporting references at all.  *Demanding* references is just noise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes definitely, although you are going to find it very hard to find documentation that clarifies this *precisely*.

Although the documentation for each of the four `GetEnumerator` overloads on this type make vague statements about returning "an enumerator that iterates through a collection", it is obvious enough that they should produce equivalent (sorted by key) sequences; remember that a sorted-dictionary is meant to  "represent a collection of key/value pairs that are sorted on the key." It would be *highly* unintuitive and confusing for users if a collection behaved completely differently (i.e. with a different enumeration order) between a `foreach` loop and a LINQ to Objects query, for example.

The best I can do is provide you with the implementations of the  two `GetEnumerator` methods you appear to be interested in (as of .NET 4.0). They are identical - they return an instance of the nested `Enumerator` type, with the *same* arguments for its constructor. The only difference is the boxing of the struct-type in the second overload:

```
// Used when you do foreach(var kvp in dict) { ... }

public Enumerator<TKey, TValue> GetEnumerator()
{
    return new Enumerator<TKey, TValue>
                ((SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>) this, 1);
}

// Used when you do:
// foreach(var kvp in (ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)dict) { ... }
// or use LINQ to Objects on the collection.

IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> 
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator()
{
    return new Enumerator<TKey, TValue>
                ((SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>) this, 1);
}
```

In fact, the only `GetEnumerator` overload that has a *slightly* different implementation is the `IDictionary.GetEnumerator` method. This changes an argument to the constructor-call such that the resulting enumerator produces `DictionaryEntry` instances rather than `KeyValuePair<,>` instances. Of course, the enumeration order will still be the same as with the other overloads.

Answer (score 11):

From the [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) for GetEnumerator:

"The dictionary is maintained in a sorted order using an internal tree. Every new element is positioned at the correct sort position, and the tree is adjusted to maintain the sort order whenever an element is removed. While enumerating, the sort order is maintained."

Specifically: "While enumerating, the sort order is maintained."

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the default `IComparer` implementation of the key, assuming you are not passing one in:

> SortedDictionary(Of TKey, TValue) requires a comparer implementation to perform key comparisons. You can specify an implementation of the IComparer(Of T) generic interface by using a constructor that accepts a comparer parameter; if you do not specify an implementation, the default generic comparer Comparer(Of T).Default is used. If type TKey implements the System.IComparable(Of T) generic interface, the default comparer uses that implementation.

Look at the `Remarks` section of the [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) page.

So, if your key is a `string`, the string implementation of `IComparable` will be used, if an `int32` the `int32` implementation will be used.